# Удаление страницы (Word)

Tags: vba, visual-basic

Собственно, как это сделать - удалить определенную страничку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выделяем текст [так](http://www.dragondrop.com/WordCoding/word001.asp), а затем делаем [Selection.Delete()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171954(v=office.11).aspx)

Есть еще множество способов это сделать, но

- есть MSDN, где подробно описаны внутренности Office с т.з. VBA
- есть встроенная подсказка в VBA (включая автодополнение имен)

поэтому очень рекомендую попробовать самим.

Comment: хорошо, удаление ненужных страниц я сделал, но столкнулся с таким косяком, удаляя все ненужные данные, у меня смещается веерх, а в самом конце остается пустая страница.
как проверить является ли страница пустой и удалить ее?

Answer (score 0):

Вот, код, который массово удаляет страницы из документа по заданному условию:

```
Sub jumred()
Dim S As Section
For Each S In ActiveDocument.Range.Sections
DEL = True
TableCount = S.Range.Tables.Count
If TableCount >= 5 Then
R = S.Range.Tables(TableCount).Rows.Count
C = S.Range.Tables(TableCount).Columns.Count
If (Mid(S.Range.Tables(TableCount).Cell(R - 1, 3).Range, 1, 4) = "ЕВДП") And (Val(S.Range.Tables(TableCount).Cell(R - 1, C).Range) > 0) Then
DEL = False
End If
End If
If DEL Then S.Range.Delete
Next
MsgBox "Выполнено полностью", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Запуск осуществляется нажатием на клавишу F5.

[Полная статья](http://hammga.ru/blogs?id=4)